# Windows 8 smart screen

Tags: windows-8

I turned off windows 8 smartscreen. Now I want to turn it back on and now I can't select anything.

It is permanently turned off but I want it back on. I also tried that gpedit.msc or whatever it is and I changed that settings to not configured but still I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Action Center > "Change Windows SmartScreen Settings"

When you select this, a popup will open with 3 options.  The default option is the top one ("Get administrator approval before running an unrecognised app from the internet")

Alternatively, you can do this with a registry edit:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
- SmartScreenEnabled String Value

Possible Values are:

- RequireAdmin = Get administrator approval before running an
  unrecognized app from the internet
- Prompt = Warn before running an unrecognized app, but don't require
  administrator approval
- Off = Don't do anything

Hope this helps